# iOS write & read the same file

Tags: ios, swift, file, io

Dears,

this is such an obvious case that I'm sure I have misunderstood something but can somebody explain to me why such a simple write to file and re-read the same file fails ?
Of course this is not the full code, I've just reduced it to the bare minimum to exemplify my problem :

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }

    init() {
        let filename = "test.txt"
        let data: Data = "My file content test".data(using: .utf8)!
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename)
        do {
            print("dbg_001 : \(fileURL)")
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
            print("dbg_002 : \(fileURL.absoluteString)")
            let dataContent = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL.absoluteString))
            print("dbg_003")
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(String(error.localizedDescription))")
        }


    }
}
```

When I launch the app above on the iOS iPod emulator I get the following output :

```
dbg_001 : file:///Users/Joe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FC7F11C6-87C1-4536-80E5-E5E1C8C6653C/data/Containers/Data/Application/762140F3-76B0-44D1-AD48-0C89B2AAA150/Documents/test.txt
dbg_002 : file:///Users/Joe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FC7F11C6-87C1-4536-80E5-E5E1C8C6653C/data/Containers/Data/Application/762140F3-76B0-44D1-AD48-0C89B2AAA150/Documents/test.txt
Error: The file ???test.txt??? couldn???t be opened because there is no such file
```

So the write is successful but the read isn't. What am I missing ?

Tried to write to a file and consequently read the previously written data back

Comment: `URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL.absoluteString)` That's wrong... It should be `URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL.path)`, or just use `fileURL` since it's already a URL.

Comment: fileURL.path has worked (just fileURL only wouldn't compile)

Many thanks !

Comment: `try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)` doesn't work?

Comment: @Tom Larme meant to replace the entire statement `URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL.absoluteString)` with `fileURL`. There's no need to create a new `URL` from an existing `URL`.